# Post doesn't move up after clicking '(less)' in suggested edits review

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing [suggested edits](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/10000), if you click the `(more)` link, the post moves down to make space for the editor and reviewer stats, however, if you click `(less)` to close the stats, the post doesn't move back up.

Before clicking `(more)`:

> [image]

After clicking `(more)` then clicking `(less)`:

> [image]

---

#### Information

This happens for me on Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit) with Google Chrome 32.0.1700.77. Using Firefox (26.0) on the same system **did not** have this issue.

Using Chrome 34.0.1847.131 on the same computer, but in Windows 7 64-bit, **does have** this issue.

The issue appears seems to only occur on certain sites. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4787066) doesn't have the issue. [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73767) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/10000) do, however.

Comment: That's weird. It works fine for me. What OS / browser?

Comment: @acheong87 This happens for me on Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) with Google Chrome 32.0.1700.77. Using Firefox (26.0) on the same system did not have this issue.

Comment: Might be specific only to http://askubuntu.com, on Stack Overflow it works fine e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4787066

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The [SO] one you linked does in fact work without issue for me. It may be specific to certain sites; I found the issue at [gaming.SE] as well: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73767